# Count of PDO fetch returning unexpected number

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to set up a login system and am having trouble with checking the number of rows returned from my PDO call to my database. The following code should return 0 rows when a bad username and/or password is supplied, but it seems to be returning 1 row regardless of the password or username.

```
require_once("includes/database.php");
session_start();
$dbh = db_connect();
$response = array();

$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$check_login = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user=:user AND password=:password LIMIT 1";
$check_login_stmt = $dbh->prepare($check_login);
$check_login_stmt->bindParam(":user", $user);
$check_login_stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

if(!$check_login_stmt->execute()) {
    $response['code'] = "failure";
    $response['err'] = $check_login_stmt->errorInfo();
    $response['reason'] = "bad_query";
} else {
    if(count($user = $check_login_stmt->fetch()) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['pb_committee'] = $user['pb_committee'];
        $response['code'] = "success";
        $response['count'] = count($user);
    } else {
        $response['code'] = "failure";
        $response['reason'] = "bad_reqs";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

When I do a count($user = $check_login_stmt->fetchAll()) > 0 it works. But I don't understand why and I'd rather use fetch() because I'm limiting it to one row in the SELECT statement.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What is contained in that row?

Comment: @GiantofaLannister when I added print_r($user) it just says "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything passed to `count()` that isn't already an array is cast to an array.  For most things, this will result in `count()` returning `1` (`NULL` being the only exception I can think of right now).

That said, you should check `PDO`'s [fetch mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php), as you might be getting back a non-array, which would be causing the described behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have no guarantee of what `count($nonArrayVariable)` will do, but you will probably have a much better time with this:

```
} else {
   if ($check_login_statement->rowCount() > 0) {
      $user = $check_login_stmt->fetch()
      // etc.
   }
```

Note that the `> 0` is superfluous.

Also, please don't store your passwords in plain text in your DB.

Comment: The PHP documentation says rowCount() shouldn't be relied on to return the number of rows for a SELECT statement. And this isn't a user system where they can change passwords. They are given to them and it's very controlled.

Comment: @jrubins I have never had a problem using `rowCount` for that purpose with MySQL .. it may not work for some other APIs.  If you really don't trust it, then what you will have to do is fetch *all* of the rows to get the row count first, or just something like `$user = $check_login_stmt->fetch(); if ($user) { ...`

Comment: @jrubins: No matter how controlled it may be, storing them in plaintext is never a good idea.  All it takes is one disgruntled employee...